# Decode Numeric HTML Entities in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, html-entities

I need a way to transform numeric HTML entities into their plain-text character equivalent. For example, I would like to turn the entity:

```
&#0233;
```

into the character:

```
é
```

Through some googling around I found a function called [HtmlUnEditFormat](http://speeves.erikin.com/2009/06/coldfusion-replace-html-ized-characters.html), but this function only transforms named entities. Is there a way to decode numeric entities in ColdFusion?

Comment: you may find this useful as well:
<cfoutput>
 <Cfset i = 1>
 <cfloop from="1" to="1000" index="i">
  <Cfset value = chr(i)>
  chr(#i#) = #value#<br/>
 </cfloop>
</cfoutput>

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### Updated Answer:

Thanks to Todd Sharp for pointing out a very simple way to do this, using the Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils library, which is packaged with CF (and Railo), so you can just do:

```
<cfset Entity = "&##0233;" />
<cfset StrEscUtils = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils") />
<cfset Character = StrEscUtils.unescapeHTML(Entity) />
```

---

#### Original Answer:

That linked function is icky - there's no need to name them explicitly, and as you say it doesn't do numerics.

Much simpler is to let CF do the work for you - using the `XmlParse` function:

```
<cffunction name="decodeHtmlEntity" returntype="String" output="false">
    <cfargument name="Entity" type="String" hint="&##<number>; or &<name>;" />
    <cfreturn XmlParse('<xml>#Arguments.Entity#</xml>').XmlRoot.XmlText />
</cffunction>
```

That one works with Railo, I can't remember if CF supports that syntax yet though, so you might need to change it to:

```
<cffunction name="decodeHtmlEntity" returntype="String" output="false">
    <cfargument name="Entity" type="String" hint="&##<number>; or &<name>;" />
    <cfset var XmlDoc = XmlParse('<xml>#Arguments.Entity#</xml>') />
    <cfreturn XmlDoc.XmlRoot.XmlText />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: For a more lightweight option, we should in theory be able to dip into the Java classes that are used to implement XmlParse and find the specific entity decoding/resolving method to use - but I've just been looking through the apidocs and not been able to find anything.

Comment: This is excellent and works well, many thanks! For fun I've been digging into a Java solution to this and found that the Apache commons string escaping utilities contains an *unescapeHtml* function. Docs here: http://tinyurl.com/3n9pem That might do the same thing with less overhead, but it requires installing a new Java class on the server, restarting, etc. so I haven't tried it yet. For now, this works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, CF ships with Apache commons, so you could simply do the following:<cfset utils = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils") />
<cfdump var="#utils#">
<cfoutput>#utils.unescapeHTML(htmlEncodedString)#</cfoutput>

Comment: Todd, you should add that as a standalone answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another function that will decode all the numeric html character entities in a string. It doesn't rely on xml parsing so it will work on strings that contain unbalanced xml tags. It's not efficient if the string has a large number of entities, but it's pretty good if there are none/few. I have only tested this on Railo, not AdobeCF.

```
<cffunction name="decodeHtmlEntities" returntype="String" output="false">
    <cfargument name="s" type="String"/>
    <cfset var LOCAL = {f = ReFind("&##([0-9]+);", ARGUMENTS.s, 1, true), map={}}>
    <cfloop condition="LOCAL.f.pos[1] GT 0">
        <cfset LOCAL.map[mid(ARGUMENTS.s, LOCAL.f.pos[1], LOCAL.f.len[1])] = chr(mid(ARGUMENTS.s, LOCAL.f.pos[2], LOCAL.f.len[2]))>
        <cfset LOCAL.f = ReFind("&##([0-9]+);", ARGUMENTS.s, LOCAL.f.pos[1]+LOCAL.f.len[1], true)>
    </cfloop>
    <cfloop collection=#LOCAL.map# item="LOCAL.key">
        <cfset ARGUMENTS.s = Replace(ARGUMENTS.s, LOCAL.key, LOCAL.map[LOCAL.key], "all")>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn ARGUMENTS.s />
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite easy to code one up yourself.  Just edit the HtmlUNEditFormat() func you found, to include them to the end of the lEntities & lEntitiesChars.

Comment: I think there are something like over 100,000 potential numeric entities. I could definitely add a few hundred and cover the most-used entities, but I was hoping for something that would cover everything.

Comment: If you were going down this route (don't; see my answer) you could do something like `Chr(rereplace(Arguments.Entity,'\D',''))` - after determining if it was a decimal entity. Hex entities would be similar but would need to convert the hex to decimal to use the Chr function.

Comment: (Oh, and there should be an 'all' argument at the end of the above rereplace call)

Comment: Actually, I would not be surprised if this approach would turn out as way faster than XML-parsing a single character with each function call. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while working with a method that, by black-box principle, can't trust that an incoming string is either HTML entity encoded or that it is not.

I've adapted Peter Boughton's function so that it can be used safely on strings that haven't already been treated with HTML entities. (The only time this seems to matter is when loose ampersands - i.e. "Cats & Dogs" - are present in the target string.) This modified version will also fail somewhat gracefully on any unforseen XML parse error.

```
<cffunction name="decodeHtmlEntity" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="str" type="string" hint="&##<number>; or &<name>;" />
    <cfset var XML = '<xml>#arguments.str#</xml>' />
    <cfset var XMLDoc = '' />

    <!--- ampersands that aren't pre-encoded as entities cause errors --->
    <cfset XML = REReplace(XML, '&(?!(\##\d{1,3}|\w+);)', '&amp;', 'all') />

    <cftry>
        <cfset XMLDoc = XmlParse(XML) />
        <cfreturn XMLDoc.XMLRoot.XMLText />
        <cfcatch>
            <cfreturn arguments.str />
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
</cffunction>
```

This would support the following use case safely:

```
<cffunction name="notifySomeoneWhoCares" access="private" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="str" type="string" required="true"
        hint="String of unknown preprocessing" />
    <cfmail from="process@domain.com" to="someoneWhoCares@domain.com"
        subject="Comments from Web User" format="html">
        Some Web User Spoke Thus:<br />
        <cfoutput>#HTMLEditFormat(decodeHTMLEntity(arguments.str))#</cfoutput>
    </cfmail>
</cffunction>
```

This function is now incredibly useful for ensuring web-submitted content is entity-safe (think XSS) before it's sent out by email or submitted into a database table.

Hope this helps.