# Coldfusion - XML formatting a string returned from API call

Tags: xml, parsing, coldfusion, special-characters

We call an API that returns a string of XML-formatted data. We'd like to convert this string into a ColdFusion XML object, via XMLParse(). A problem occurs when special characters show up in the data values. For example, characters like this:

`&nbsp; &mdash; &ndash;`

(yes, the raw data contains them in their HTML encoded equivalent). When doing the XMLParse(), it throws an error on these encoded characters. Here is an example that will error:

Part of our string:
`<event>Hello &nbsp; World</event>`

Error:
`Reference to undefined entity "&nbsp;"`

What's the best method to make these characters compatible with the XMLParse()? And even more important - how can we do this if we don't always know what the characters will be?

Thanks!

(this is on a ColdFusion 6 server)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

```
ReplaceList(xml, "&nbsp;,&mdash;,&ndash;", "#Chr(160)#,#Chr(8212)#,#Chr(8211)#")
```

Wikipedia seems to have [a quite complete list of character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) and their char codes. I would opt for using `Chr()` to create the replacement string, this way you can be unambiguous and independent of source-code file encoding.

Comment: The only drawback: if you need to know that something was an entity vs. a specific character, this method will obscure that info.

Comment: An entity and a specific character are *the same thing*, just serialized differently. There is no need to make such a distinction unless you're doing something wrong. From the DOM's point of view, a `©` is a `©`, no matter if you used `&copy;`, `&#169`, `&#xA9;` or a literal `©` to express it in the HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(xml, '&','&amp;','all');
```

should allow it to be validated.  You can also use a DTD to define these characters but as you stated you don't always know that the characters will be - I would probably just do the replace.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a pretty good function to remove extended characters and replace them with their HTML equivalent.

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/202.cfm

Answer (score 1):

See this related question: [Decode Numeric HTML Entities in ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646839/decode-numeric-html-entities-in-coldfusion)

Use that, and then XmlFormat() it, then XmlParse() it.

"nbsp is not one of the 5 predefined character entity references", [@stevenerat said](http://twitter.com/stevenerat/statuses/5429105926).

Answer (score 1):

Yup, nbsp is not one of the predefined character entity referneces and needs to be escaped with xmlformat() such as xmlparse(xmlformat(theString)).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/00000668.htm

Comment: Using `XmlFormat()` on `theString` would change `&nbsp;` to `&amp;nbsp;`. You *could* possibly parse the string as XML after that, but the data the string contained would be changed. Apart from that, `XmlFormat()` would change `<` to `&lt;` etc. - so you would turn all the HTML markup to text. Not what the OP intends, I think.

Comment: Tomalak is correct. This changes the original data & conversion issues.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the "&" with `"&amp;"` and then back again after parsing seems to work

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xmlString">
    <event>Hello&nbsp;World&amp;</event>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset xmlString = Replace(xmlString, "&", "&amp;", "all") />
<cfset doc = Xmlparse(xmlString) />
<cfset value = Replace(doc.event.xmlText, "&amp;", "&","all") />
```

Answer (score -2):

You might take a look at [XmlFormat()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/6/CFML_Reference/functions-pt2120.htm). Easy to use:

```
<cfset string = XmlFormat(string)>
```

Comment: How is that going to help? The whole string will end up double-encoded, which makes it even less fit for XML parsing than before.

Comment: Tomalak is correct...this causes more of a problem because XMLParse() will get hung up on these new chars.

Comment: yikes, yeah, this will escape the entities too so it's no longer XML. I'll read a little closer next time.