# How to decode French html entities in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, decode

I have tried a couple different things including urldecode() as well as a few different answers from this question: [Decode Numeric HTML Entities in ColdFusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646839/decode-numeric-html-entities-in-coldfusion)

For example I have this french text:

```
&nbsp;Apr&egrave;s avoir termin&eacute;
```

I need to convert to the actual french characters, including the space at the beginning to this:

```
 Après avoir terminé
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Apache Commons library to do this:

```
<cfset input = "&nbsp;Apr&egrave;s avoir termin&eacute;" />
<cfset utils = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils") />
<cfdump var=#utils.unescapeHTML(input)# />
```

(p.s. This was hidden in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646839/decode-numeric-html-entities-in-coldfusion#comment19587816_1647085) to my answer on the question you linked to, though I've since edited into the main answer to increase visibility.)