# coldfusion/Java replacing html entities with unicode characters

Tags: java, coldfusion

I have text like

```
    pr&#225;zdninov&253; komplex pon&#250;ka viacer&#233; mo&#382;nosti
 ubytovania. V are&#225;li je recepcia, re&scaron;taur&#225;cia, 
snackbar a pizzeria. Moderne zariaden&#233; apartm&#225;ny 
vo vilk&#225;ch: obytn&#233; jednotky na dvoch poschodiach, na pr&#237;zem&#237; a poschod&#237; s balk&#243;nom a terasou s n&#225;bytkom a
 malou z&#225;hradkou. V rezidenci&#225;ch: na pr&#237;zem&#237; 
alebo poschod&#237; s balk&#243;nom alebo terasou, ako aj s  
n&#225;bytkom. V&scaron;etky apartm&#225;ny maj&#250; SAT-TV, trezor, 
klimatiz&#225;ciu, modern&#250; kuchynsk&#250; 
linku, k&#225;vovar, mikrovlnn&#250; r&#250;ru 
a chladni&#269;ku s mrazni&#269;kou,
```

And I am trying to replacing the codes with unicode characters in coldfusion like

```
XmlParse("<xml>#text#</xml>").XmlRoot.XmlText
```

Somehow it's not working for many characters.
And Idea to  do this in an other way-

Comment: You seem to be asking the same thing as this: [Decode Numeric HTML Entities in ColdFusion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646839/decode-numeric-html-entities-in-coldfusion) - summary is: use [Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)