# Special characters are displaying in hexdecimal

Tags: html, coldfusion

I saved a text ,

```
Anticoagulation with HGB change =2 and HGB <7
```

But it displaying as below in the UI

```
Anticoagulation with HGB change &#x3d;2 and HGB <7
```

Please tell how to fix this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Use innerHTML instead of innerText or replace `&#x3d;` with `=`

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646839/decode-numeric-html-entities-in-coldfusion

Comment: What is the value in database after you save it?

Comment: The value saved in database is : Anticoagulation with HGB change &#x3d;2 and HGB &lt;7

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is when text is encoded for security reasons. There are a collection of `encodeFor*` functions that started appearing in CF 10 in order to combat Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

- [encodeForHTML()](https://cfdocs.org/encodeforhtml)

```
<cfset txt = "Anticoagulation with HGB change =2 and HGB <7">

<cfoutput>#encodeForHTML(txt)#</cfoutput>

<cfoutput>#encodeForJavaScript(txt)#</cfoutput>
```

The output is encoded in context to the type of output you need.

```
Anticoagulation with HGB change &#x3d;2 and HGB &lt;7

Anticoagulation\x20with\x20HGB\x20change\x20\x3D2\x20and\x20HGB\x20\x3C7
```

But the fact that the "less than" sign is not encoded makes me wonder how this text was stored and displayed.

Additional Note: The old-school way of "encoding" text was using `encodeForHTML()`.

```
<cfoutput>#encodeForHTML(txt)#</cfoutput>
```

But that only encodes a handful of characters, so it has been deprecated for the new functions.

```
Anticoagulation with HGB change =2 and HGB &lt;7
```

Need more details:

- Is this text saved in the database?
- Is this text saved in the database with the encoded equals sign?
- Is the text being encoded BEFORE being saved in the database? (Hint: It should not be.)

**UPDATE**

> - And yes we are doing encodeforhtml() i.e we are encoding before saving the name in the database
> - I just searched on the internet and found a method : DecodeforHTML in coldfusion. Can I use this?

You should sanitize all user-supplied data using an AntiSamy filter before saving it to the database. This would block XSS and other security threats from making it into the database in the first place. These encoding functions and related processes are meant to address the potential risk of unsanitized data that exists in the database, new or old.

Recent versions of CF can use `getSafeHTML()` to provide data sanitization.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getsafehtml.html

So ideally. save the data in the database unencoded, then encode the data based on context when you need to display it. If that's not possible, then yes, `decodeForHTML` is exactly the opposite of `encodeForHTML` and you can use that. However, you may have a problem in the future if you need to use this text as a string with JavaScript. In that case, you'd have to `decodeForHTML`, then `encodeForJavaScript`.

Comment: The text in database is saved as : Anticoagulation with HGB change &#x3d;2 and HGB &lt;7

Comment: And yes we are doing encodeforhtml() i.e we are encoding before saving the name in the database

Comment: I just searched on the internet and found a method : DecodeforHTML in coldfusion. Can I use this?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno on the whole good advice, but the encoding should occur being *using* the text, not before storing it. The encoding schema to use varies by situation (html, js, html attributes, xml etc), so it should take place when the usage is known (when using it), not when storing it. Stuff like detected XSS attempts should be outright *rejected* and not stored at all in the first place. It does look like the OP is double-encoding stuff though. Encode text once, in the correct way, at the point it needs encoding (when it's being output).